# What is the minimum sample size for panel data analysis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, panel-data, small-sample

I am working with a panel data and want to perform a regression analysis (OLS, fixed effects model or random effects model). The panel data is unbalanced with $T$ varying from 7 to 13, and $N=11$. I am confused about having a small number of observations (around 100).

What is the minimum time observations and cross-sectional observations to perform a statistically significant panel analysis. And what are the alternatives if my dataset is too small?

Comment: What is N in your case? Individuals, firms, countries? You have time series with different lengths? Or you have holes in your time series?